# Removing Express Post shipping from some items only

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

I want to remove Express Post shipping from some big items (Air cons, Big desktop machines...etc) that would cost the buyer a fortune in Express Post payment.

I've found in the Fontis Australia /app/ code I can remove Express completely but cannot find a way to remove it from only a handful of items.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: If you know basic knowledge of Magento module creation then you can do it by observer

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean?